# Filter table with any value from other table column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

How to write select in oracle to filter value in one table with any value from other table column.

To be clear, I have two table. For Example Car and Colors.

In Car table I have two columns, car_model and car_color, in Colors table I have col_code and col_color columns.

I need to select all car_model where car_color = any color from col_color column from colors table.

Something like pseudo:

```
Select car_model From car Where car_color = color.col_color
```

Comment: You should learn a little about join in sql. It will be useful for you. Even just the bascis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` (acually, outer join) like this:

```
select car.car_model, color.col_color from car left join color on car.car_color = color.col_code
```

Or, if you like it more,

```
select car.car_model, color.col_color from car, color where car.car_color = color.col_code
```

which is actually inner joins tables. You may find information on different types of joins in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: There is a huge difference between 1st and 2nd query: 1st is the LEFT JOIN and the second is INNER(implicitly) JOIN. Topic author should know it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need any joins, it is the unintuitive way to write your query.

```
select car_model
from car
where car_color in (select col_color from color)
```